# How to perform an integer division in Assembly? Illegal override register error

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

By far, I've come up with a way how to get Integers from input and how to output them. Now it would be cool If I could perform integer division. Could anybody please give me a hint on how it's basically done? And why I am getting this error?

Here's the code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 200h
.DATA
    InAMess DB 'Enter A:',0ah,'$'
    InBMess DB 'Enter B:',0ah,'$'
    Res DB 'Result of two integer division:$'

    a dw 0
    b dw 0
.CODE
start:
mov ax, @Data
mov ds, ax

jmp action

inputNumber proc
    nextchar:
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h 
    cmp al, 2fh
    jl outp 

    sub al, 30h
    xor ah, ah
    xchg ax, bx
    mov dx, 0Ah
    mul dx
    add bx, ax

    jmp nextchar
    outp:
    ret
inputNumber endp

OutputNumber proc
    aam
    add ax, 3030h
    mov dl, ah
    mov dh, al
    mov ah, 02
    int 21h
    mov dl, dh
    int 21h
    ret
OutputNumber endp

action:

mov ah, 9h
mov dx, OFFSET InAMess
int 21h

call InputNumber
mov a, bx
mov bx, 0

mov ah, 9h
mov dx, OFFSET InBMess
int 21h

call InputNumber
mov b, bx
mov bx, 0 

mov ah, 9h
mov dx, OFFSET Res
int 21h 

;Here it is
mov dx,0
mov dx:ax, a
div b

mov ax, a
call OutputNumber

mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 0
int 21h

END start
```

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov dx:ax, a` is invalid. The `dx:ax` notation simply means you should put the high word into `dx` and the low word into `ax`. Since your `a` is a single word, and it is unsigned you can just put it into `ax` and zero `dx` (which you have already done). So:

```
mov dx, 0
mov ax, a
div b
```

Comment: But after that division I'm getting strange output when I call my OutputNumber procedure. Why is this so?

Comment: Wow, my bad. And how would I go If I wanted to add '4' to that division result?

Comment: `add ax, 4 `? Surely you know that?